# BookshelfJS: How to define relationship with a foreign key other than ID

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, bookshelf.js

I have two tables: `devices` and `diagnostics`.

A `diagnostic` is ran before a `device` is registered. There would be a `cpu_id` that is saved as part of the `diagnostic` run. Then `device` once registered would then also have a `cpu_id` recorded on it.

This is many-to-one relationship, and the foreign key here is the `chip_id`.

I tried the following for the two tables, but I got nothing:

**Device**

```
diagnostics: function () {
    var Diagnostic = require('./db').model('Diagnostic');
    return this.hasMany(Diagnostic, 'chip_id');
}
```

**Diagnostic**

```
device: function () {
    var Device = require('./config/db').model('Device');
    return this.belongsTo(Device, 'chip_id');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think you want to use the registry plugin, or re-organize your project so that you define your models in the same file if they are dependent on each other.

Answer (score -1):

you need to define the hasMany and BelongsTo in the models, then you need to retrive your relation like this

```
Book.where({id: 1}).fetch({withRelated: ['author']}).then(function(book) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(book.related('author')));
});
```

using the withRelated that marks that you need the relationship and the related function that does the eager loading

Comment: That doesn't work. I have clearly stated in my question that's what I do, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Nope, this is different, the hasmany you need to insert it in the model (that you can find searching for something that starts with bookshelf.Model.extend({ )

What you wrote is not the model, you are trying to access a method outside it's scope

Comment: That's exactly what I have done. The two codes above are inside the models of `Device` and `Diagnostics` respectively.